# Increase disk space for Fedora Live CD

Tags: linux, hard-drive, fedora, wine, livecd

I am trying install some apps on fresh fedora live cd, but with no luck.
Error message appears due installation that not enough disk space:

```
[SKIPPED] wine-stable-common-7.0.0-3.1.i686.rpm: Already downloaded                      
[SKIPPED] wine-stable64-7.0.0-3.1.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                         
[SKIPPED] winehq-stable-7.0.0-3.1.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                         
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: Transaction test error:
  installing package wine-stable-common-1:7.0.0-3.1.i686 needs 48MB more space on the / filesystem
  installing package winehq-stable-1:7.0.0-3.1.x86_64 needs 48MB more space on the / filesystem

Error Summary
-------------
Disk Requirements:
   At least 48MB more space needed on the / filesystem.

[liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0  1.8G  1 loop /mnt/loop0
loop1         7:1    0  7.5G  1 loop 
├─live-rw   253:0    0  7.5G  0 dm   /
└─live-base 253:1    0  7.5G  1 dm   /run/media/liveuser/Anaconda
loop2         7:2    0   32G  0 loop 
└─live-rw   253:0    0  7.5G  0 dm   /
sr0          11:0    1  1.9G  0 rom  /run/initramfs/live
zram0       251:0    0  6.8G  0 disk [SWAP]
vda         252:0    0 37.4G  0 disk /run/media/liveuser/disk1
[liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ df
Filesystem            1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                3539028       0   3539028   0% /dev
tmpfs                   3572540       0   3572540   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   1429016    1444   1427572   1% /run
/dev/sr0                1962240 1962240         0 100% /run/initramfs/live
/dev/mapper/live-rw     7640588 6038432   1585772  80% /
tmpfs                   3572496      60   3572436   1% /tmp
vartmp                  3572492      16   3572476   1% /var/tmp
tmpfs                    714496     156    714340   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/vda               38261900      24  36286084   1% /run/media/liveuser/disk1
/dev/loop0              1851392 1851392         0 100% /mnt/loop0
/dev/mapper/live-base   7640588 5437900   2186304  72% /run/media/liveuser/Anaconda
[liveuser@localhost-live ~]$
```

LIVE CD (FEDORA35) started with qemu boxes on HOST (FEDORA35)

Main question: how I can increase "required" disk space?
Thanks

Comment: could you solve your problem?

Comment: nope) not yet...

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the build in a docker was failing, but in a running Fedora (the same version as the target LIVE CD ISO) it was working fine.

```
sudo dnf -y install livecd-tools fedora-kickstarts zstd mc  # /usr/share/spin-kickstarts

# xfce add space : vi fedora-live-base.ks  # part / --size 14000
# ws fedora-live-workstation.ks part / --size 14000
## !! uncomment rawhide :: fedora-repo.ks
## for fedora 35 : comment 'auth' in fedora-live-base
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can You add link to full video instruction, because currently it is not clear for me at all.
My livecd (fedora 35) initial setup was with "boxes" app in fedora 35 OS (without docker). Thanks

Comment: Additional clarification would be very welcome. I don't understand it.